# Is there a way to check if a library has been built for little endian or big endian architecture without executing it's code?

Tags: c, endianness

Is there a way to check if a library has been built for little endian or big endian architecture without executing it's code?

Let's say, I have a library X, but, I don't know if it has been built for little endian or big endian, is there any command or is there a way to find out through the build output if the library has been built for little endian or big endian? Or is it possible to place this information in the library?

Comment: What format is the library in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you are running linux/unix, the easiest way is using file command.

```
$ file /lib64/libc-2.15.so 
/lib64/libc-2.15.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[sha1]=0x2dc710cc03932ca6fb7f223e2c0f67e21adebb4f, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped
```

So the information is definitely built into the library header. You can check using readelf command.

```
$ readelf -h /lib64/libc-2.15.so
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x3fc4c21840
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          2062800 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         10
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         43
  Section header string table index: 42
```

In windows, I don't know how to check, but should be there in the header of the dll.

Comment: I suppose that it's "`LSB`" that indicates that it's little endian, but I don't think that's self evident (to me "LSB" means least significant byte). I think you should mention what's indicating that its little endian in that output (and what the output would have been in case of big endian).

Answer (score 1):

There are few extant machines where you could run little endian or big endian code on the same hardware, so the question is almost immaterial.  IIRC, there were some machines (MIPS RISC machines?) that could run big endian or little endian, and could be switched at runtime if desired.

However, if your library was compiled for x86/64 (a little endian architecture), it won't work on SPARC or PPC (big endian architectures), but the problem is not the endianness, but the fact that the machine code for the different chips is quite different and incompatible.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bi-endian_hardware) lists ARM, PowerPC, Alpha, SPARC V9, MIPS, PA-RISC, SuperH SH-4 and IA-64 as *bi-endian* (capable of running both little and big endian code)

Comment: @osgx: that's interesting; I was not aware that the list was so extensive.  AFAIK, though, the normal mode of operation for SPARC and PowerPC is big endian — or, at least, that's the mode I've seen them run in for Solaris and AIX respectively.